# Javascript import of Typescript - exporting default object

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, export

This may have been answered somehow already, but wasn't sure how to ask it.

I have a Typescript file that exports a single class:

```
export class MyClass {
    ...
}
```

I have a Javascript file that imports the transpiled version of that typescript and uses it:

```
define('random-source', ['src/my-class'], function(MyClassMod) {
    ...
    var myClass = new MyClassMod.MyClass();
    ...
});
```

My question is this:  Is there a way to write the Typescript file so that the only object exported is that 'MyClass' definition?  As you see from the define in the Javascript, it's imported as a module name, but I have to say '.MyClass' to access it.  When I have a lot of Typescript files with a single class defined like this, it makes the Javascript code a bit messy.  Ideally I'd like something like:

```
define('random-source', ['src/my-class'], function(MyClass) {
    ...
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    ...
});
```

Is that possible?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why write code in javascript if you are using typescript?

Comment: can you use `import` ? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: I'm working on a legacy application where the new stuff we're writing is in Typescript and slowly converting over existing Javascript files.  But in the meantime, we need to be able to pull in transpiled Typescript files into the legacy Javascript files for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are looking for an export assignment, which will make `MyClass` the value of the entire module:

```
class MyClass {
    // ...
}
export = MyClass;
```

Comment: Thanks Matt!  That was what I wanted.  I'm a long-time C++ guy new to the web dev world and I couldn't find the answer to this seemingly simple issue...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for a default export:

```
export default class MyClass {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hello.  That doesn't work.  In my javascript file I need to do "new MyClassMod.default()" to get it to execute.

Comment: @Steve that's because you are using AMD modules in your target script. You should either use ES6 modules import in your target to make it work this way or use AMD modules in your TypeScript source.